# How to get weights from .pb model in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I trained one model and then create one .pb file by freeze that model.
so, my question is how to get weights from .pb file or i have to do more process for get weights

@mrry, please guide me.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not mrry, but freezing a model gets you a GraphDef; you can [parse a GraphDef in Python](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/tool_developers/#graphdef), which will have the values of constants (including your frozen weights).

Comment: ohk.. thank you so much ..

Answer (score 22):

Let us first load the graph from `.pb` file.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.platform import gfile

GRAPH_PB_PATH = './model/tensorflow_inception_v3_stripped_optimized_quantized.pb' #path to your .pb file
with tf.Session(config=config) as sess:
  print("load graph")
  with gfile.FastGFile(GRAPH_PB_PATH,'rb') as f:
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    sess.graph.as_default()
    tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')
    graph_nodes=[n for n in graph_def.node]
```

Now when you freeze a graph to `.pb` file your variables are converted to `Const` type and the weights which were trainabe variables would also be stored as `Const` in `.pb` file. `graph_nodes` contains all the nodes in graph. But we are interested in all the `Const` type nodes.

```
wts = [n for n in graph_nodes if n.op=='Const']
```

Each element of `wts` is of NodeDef type. It has several atributes such as name, op etc. The values can be extracted as follows -

```
from tensorflow.python.framework import tensor_util

for n in wts:
    print "Name of the node - %s" % n.name
    print "Value - " 
    print tensor_util.MakeNdarray(n.attr['value'].tensor)
```

Hope this solves your concern.

Comment: how do i load the pb file then then use it ? like network = load_pb_file(Alexnet.pb)

network.run(image)

Comment: hello ? What is a pb file ? How can I use it ? I have an AlexNet.pb

Comment: @kong Yes, the pb file is the frozen file. Alexnet.pb is the one for you.

Comment: graph_def.ParseFromString

Comment: `sess.graph.as_default()`seems not to be needed as when session is opened with `with` it is automatically set as default one.