# Tensorflow: How to create const node and add to graph?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have existing model that is stored in `.pb`, I want to add some constant tensor (initially I have data in numpy array) to some tensor in graph via `Add` op, how can it be done?

As I understand each node in graph is `tensorflow.core.framework.node_def_pb2.NodeDef`, so I need create one node for `Add` op and one node for const tensor?

These are related questions:

[TensorFlow Manual Construction of GraphDef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42168977/tensorflow-manual-construction-of-graphdef)

[How to get weights from .pb model in Tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46127471/get-the-value-weights-from-pb-file-by-tensorflow)

Answer (score 6):

EDIT: The answer below is just to add a disconnected constant to a graph, if you want to add a new adding operation then it would be something like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

constant_value = ...
with tf.Graph().as_default():
    gd = tf.GraphDef()
    with open('my_graph.pb', 'rb') as f:
        gd.MergeFromString(f.read())
    my_tensor = tf.import_graph_def(gd, name='', return_elements='SomeOperation:0')
    tf.add(my_tensor, constant_value, name='NewOperation')
    tf.train.write_graph(tf.get_default_graph(), '.',
                         'my_modified_graph.pb', as_text=False)
```

Note however this just adds new operations, it does *not* modify the value of the original tensor. I'm not sure which one of these is what you wanted.

---

The most practical way is to import the graph, add the constant and save it again:

```
import tensorflow as tf

new_constant = ...
with tf.Graph().as_default():
    gd = tf.GraphDef()
    with open('my_graph.pb', 'rb') as f:
        gd.MergeFromString(f.read())
    tf.import_graph_def(gd, name='')
    tf.constant(new_constant, name='NewConstant')
    tf.train.write_graph(tf.get_default_graph(), '.',
                         'my_graph_with_constant.pb', as_text=False)
```

If for some reason you don't want to import the graph, you can manually build the node object like this:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.core.framework.tensor_pb2 import TensorProto
from tensorflow.core.framework.tensor_shape_pb2 import TensorShapeProto

# New constant to add
my_value = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5,6]], dtype=np.int32)
# Make graph node
tensor_content = my_value.tobytes()
dt = tf.as_dtype(my_value.dtype).as_datatype_enum
tensor_shape = TensorShapeProto(dim=[TensorShapeProto.Dim(size=s) for s in my_value.shape])
tensor_proto = TensorProto(tensor_content=tensor_content,
                           tensor_shape=tensor_shape,
                           dtype=dt)
node = tf.NodeDef(name='MyConstant', op='Const',
                  attr={'value': tf.AttrValue(tensor=tensor_proto),
                        'dtype': tf.AttrValue(type=dt)})
# Read existing graph
gd = tf.GraphDef()
with open('my_graph.pb', 'rb') as f:
    gd.MergeFromString(f.read())
# Add new node
gd.node.extend([node])
# Save modified graph
tf.train.write_graph(tf.get_default_graph(), '.',
                     'my_graph_with_constant.pb', as_text=False)
```

Note this case is relatively easy because the node is not connected to any other node.

Comment: Actually I don't see `NewConstant` in new saved `.pb` maybe because it's don't connected to main graph? And I need to add const tensor to some existing tensor.

Comment: @mrgloom Ah wait I didn't understand that right, I thought you just wanted to have the constant in the graph.

Comment: @mrgloom Okay I edited for the addition. However, as I point out, I'm not sure if what you want is to introduce a new addition operation (what I posted) or actually modify the existing value of a tensor (a bit more complicated).

Comment: One problem is seems when I call `tf.import_graph_def` 2 times to add 2 constants, it creates copy of graph each time(so I have 2 graphs in .pb each with one constant added), second problem is that `Pack` operation is added before added `Add` operation which is not desired effect.